# How to get Row Id in RepositoryLookupEdit_ValueChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms, grid, devexpress, repositorylookupedit

I have gridcontrol that has a RepositoryLookupEdit in one of the columns. I can get the value of RepositoryLookupEdit after changed, but I dont know how to get the which row's RepositoryLookupEdit value changed. How can I get the Row ID?

With the code below, I can get the RepositoryLookupEdit value.

```
private void repositoryItemLookUpEdit1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LookUpEdit edit = sender as LookUpEdit;
    var row = edit.Properties.GetDataSourceRowByKeyValue(edit.EditValue);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since repositoryItemLookUpEdit isn't restricted to GridControls you cannot get the row handle from this event.  You however have other possibilities.

First, if the edit is done by the user, you can use the ColumnView.GetFocusedRow() method to get the current grid row.

If however the edit value is changed via code it will also be changed in the grid so you can now use the ColumnView.CellValueChanged event.

```
private void repositoryItemLookUpEdit1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LookUpEdit edit = sender as LookUpEdit;
    var row = edit.Properties.GetDataSourceRowByKeyValue(edit.EditValue);
    gridRow = gridView.GetFocusedRow() as MyDataRow
}
```